# How to assign 1000, 1000+1 for unique string value of another column in same Pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, function, numpy, dataframe

Trying to create another column starting with 1000, 1001, 1002 and so on, based on unique string value of another column in same dataframe.

df:

```
        unique_value
0       xyz123
1       xyz123
2       xyz123
3       xyz123
4       xyz985
5       abc987
6       eff987
7       asd541
```

Desired output:

```
        unique_value        ID
0       xyz123              1000
1       xyz123              1000
2       xyz123              1000
3       xyz123              1000
4       xyz985              1001
5       abc987              1002
6       eff987              1003
7       asd541              1004
```

Here's what I have set up so far:

```
df['ID'] = df['unique_value'].apply()
```

Is there any conditional lambda function, or any numpy function that I can use?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pd.factorize`

```
df['ID'] = pd.factorize(df['unique_value'])[0] + 1000

Out[60]:
  unique_value    ID
0       xyz123  1000
1       xyz123  1000
2       xyz123  1000
3       xyz123  1000
4       xyz985  1001
5       abc987  1002
6       eff987  1003
7       asd541  1004
```

Comment: Thanks @Andy. Two Questions: why is there a [0] index at the end of the line? is there a way to use .apply and lambda for this to increase process time?

Comment: @Mick: pd.factorize returns tuple of arrays where  `0` is codes and `1` is unique values. We need codes so we index `[0]`.  `pd.factorize` is a built-in vectorized method which is much faster than using `apply`